# SMTP fails using Thunderbird after dropping Comcast, installing CenturyLink

Tags: smtp

On two Windows 7 PC's, an Android tablet, and Android phone, a dozen email accounts have been working fine for many years. I disconnected Comcast and installed CenturyLink service using Actiontec Q1000 router / modem which I bought at an estate sale and reset.

SMTP now fails every time we try to send a message using Thunderbird. Incoming email works fine. Only the ISP changed. CenturyLink says they removed filtering for Port 25 (whatever that means) but I still have the same problem.

Of possible interest is the fact the CD installation process for the  new router failed and displayed a message to call tech support, which I did, and they got the router going as far as web surfing. My tech skills are pretty good, web developer / programmer, and I host 80 client domains and provide email service for hundreds of people. But this issue has me and CenturyLink dumfounded.

Thunderbird error: "The message could not be sent because the connection to SMTP server blahblah.com timed out. Try again or contact your network administrator."

I know positively the server is fine, hundreds of people are using it for email, no one else has any issues. We checked the router firewall to make sure SMTP is allowed both incoming and outgoing.

Comment: @greg Bowser is on the right track with his answer.  Give us a hint at least on whose smtp server you are trying to use, and I assume it's not comcasts.  Independent hosting company?  as greg point out port 587, or perhaps 465 should get you going..

Answer (score 0):

I would not take CenturyLink's word that they are not filtering port 25. Blocking port 25 is a *very* common measure taken by ISPs to prevent botted machines from being used to send spam. Does the SMTP server you're using also allow port 587? 587 is the standard for submission now. It's worth a try before any more advanced troubleshooting.

You know that you can't connect on port 25, but you don't know *where* that connection is failing. A good way of figuring this out is with a TCP traceroute. In brief, you could fire up a Linux install (or live cd) and do two traceroutes as follows (change hostname as appropriate):

```
[root@gamma ~]# traceroute -T -p 25 smtpserv.uri.edu
traceroute to smtpserv.uri.edu (131.128.1.40), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home (192.168.1.1)  1.093 ms  1.092 ms  1.090 ms
 2  lo0-100.PRVDRI-VFTTP-303.verizon-gni.net (100.40.70.1)  6.626 ms  6.628 ms  6.626 ms
 3  T1-5-0-2.PRVDRI-LCR-22.verizon-gni.net (100.41.218.154)  9.452 ms T1-5-0-3.PRVDRI-LCR-21.verizon-gni.net (100.41.218.156)  10.893 ms T1-5-0-2.PRVDRI-LCR-22.verizon-gni.net (100.41.218.154)  9.441 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 (no replies after this point)


[root@gamma ~]# traceroute  smtpserv.uri.edu
traceroute to smtpserv.uri.edu (131.128.1.40), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home (192.168.1.1)  1.248 ms  1.241 ms  1.239 ms
 2  lo0-100.PRVDRI-VFTTP-303.verizon-gni.net (100.40.70.1)  9.302 ms  9.305 ms  9.303 ms
 3  T1-5-0-3.PRVDRI-LCR-21.verizon-gni.net (100.41.218.156)  13.585 ms T1-5-0-2.PRVDRI-LCR-22.verizon-gni.net (100.41.218.154)  12.165 ms T1-5-0-2.PRVDRI-LCR-21.verizon-gni.net (100.41.218.152)  13.582 ms
 4  xe-3-0-8-0.BOS-BB-RTR2.verizon-gni.net (130.81.163.188)  12.162 ms * xe-11-1-0-0.NY5030-BB-RTR1.verizon-gni.net (130.81.163.180)  16.170 ms
 5  * * *
 6  0.ae2.BR3.NYC4.ALTER.NET (140.222.229.99)  16.828 ms * *
 (etc: this traceroute completes)
```

The first traceroute is using TCP port 25. The second is using some random UDP port, and it gets all the way to the destination. The second traceroute is my control: it shows me that I *can* successfully reach the destination host. The first one shows that my connection attempts on port 25 are dying between hops 3 and 4: this is where my ISP is blocking port 25.

Comment: I ran Windows command: tracert fiesta.websitewelcome.com and it displayed something like 1 1MS 1MS <1MS 192.168.0.1 followed by other attempts reading REQUEST TIMED OUT

Comment: Secure SSL/TLS Settings (Recommended)
Username: test@phpvs.com
Password: test123!

Incoming Server: fiesta.websitewelcome.com
IMAP Port: 993
POP3 Port: 995

Outgoing Server: fiesta.websitewelcome.com
SMTP Port: 465
Authentication is required for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP.

Comment: So you should be able to configure using SSL and port 465 and avoid the whole port 25 debacle.

The windows tracert command does not work the same as the Linux one. It lacks useful functionality. It just does what it does.

Comment: Got the Gmail account to work with Thunderbird after following advice at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=1470805 which included Connection Security: STARTTLS ... the above test@phpvs.com example should be a working example if anyone cares to try it.

Comment: I second that. If your mail provider uses a standard encrypted smtp port, use that port. Some providers are also using port 2525.